# HLS from raspberry pi to mobile (Android or iOS) through server

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to make a live stream from raspberry to Android through the internet.

I searched through the web and I'm actually able to stream from the raspberry, and read the stream from mobile when the mobile is directly connected to the raspberry.

But if I want to make it online, there is something I'm missing on how to "pipe" this stream through another server.

So mainly I want to check how to post the stream to a server, and how to retrieve it from a mobile in realtime.

I already checked the following :

[Http Live Streaming with the Apache web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126594/http-live-streaming-with-the-apache-web-server)

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7446/how-can-i-stream-h-264-video-from-the-raspberry-pi-camera-module-via-a-web-serve

https://docs.peer5.com/guides/setting-up-hls-live-streaming-server-using-nginx/

Comment: https://github.com/jaredpetersen/raspi-live ;;;; https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5077/http-live-streaming ;;;; https://jobinbasani.com/2014/08/23/nginx-based-streaming-server-raspberry-pi/ ;;;;

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Hyde, but the streaming from the pi is solved from my side, but in my case the web browser cannot be connected directly to the pi, I need to connect to an external server, and streaming pi->external server -> client is the issue i'm trying to solve

Comment: How about this ones: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=56149 ;;;; https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/1562 ;;;; https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/53954/how-to-connect-to-raspberry-pi-outside-of-local-network-without-port-forwarding ;;;; https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/71493 ;;;; As I see, it's about `port forwarding`. Please google it: `raspberry pi streaming port forwarding tutorial`.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i needed!I'll search through these, but at least i know where to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to forward your port to an external port on a web server.
There are some tutorials which you able to [find them](https://www.google.com/search?q=raspberry%20pi%20streaming%20port%20forwarding%20tutorial&oq=raspberry%20pi%20streaming%20port%20forwarding%20tutorial) by this keywords:

```
raspberry pi streaming port forwarding tutorial
```

Some of the useful links are:

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=56149
- https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/1562
- https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/53954/how-to-connect-to-raspberry-pi-outside-of-local-network-without-port-forwarding
- https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/71493

Especially these:

- https://jacobsalmela.com/2014/05/31/raspberry-pi-webcam-using-mjpg-streamer-over-internet/
- https://videos.cctvcamerapros.com/raspberry-pi/ip-camera-raspberry-pi-youtube-live-video-streaming-server.html