# procedure to stream video from a server (using Apache or Ngnix) and send it to EXO player?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, exoplayer, ffserver

I want to implement an server streaming concept. what is the way for doing this? web server type(Apache or nginx)? packages for handling streaming from server to players(e.g ffmpeg)? 
what is the position of ffserver here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Http Live Streaming with the Apache web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126594/http-live-streaming-with-the-apache-web-server)

Comment: this is not my question.I am beginner in this field. actually i want to know about position of ffmpeg, ffserver and also web servers in receiving streamed data from a server and also about their alternatives. I will appreciate if someone could explain whole direction for receiving stream data from a server for a player like exo and there also explain concepts that are asked for.